# Using Proxy auth with LibCurl in C++

Tags: c++, libcurl

I tried to create http get request using libcurl in c++.First i used this code (without proxy and it worked)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{

   CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
     
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stackoverflow.com/");


        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Second i tried to use proxy auth with username and password but i didnt get any response.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

    int main(void)
    {
    
       CURL* curl;
        CURLcode res;
    
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
         
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stackoverflow.com/");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "here is my proxy");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "my username");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "my pass");
    
            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    
            /* always cleanup */
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I dont know why it is not working.
*Proxy is tested in c# and it works*

Answer (score 2):

Found answer just replace *CURLOPT_USERNAME* with *CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME*
and *CURLOPT_PASSWORD* with  *CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD*.
working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stackoverflow.com/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy:port");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME, "username");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD, "password");
       curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```